# Grouping data into ranges in R

Tags: r, grouping

Suppose I have a data frame in **R** that has names of students in one column and their marks in another column. These marks range from 20 to 100.

```
> mydata  
id  name   marks gender  
1   a1    56     female  
2   a2    37      male
```

I want to divide the student into groups, based on the criteria of obtained marks, so that difference between marks in each group should be more than 10. I tried to use the function table, which gives the number of students in each range from say 20-30, 30-40, but I want it to pick those students that have marks in a given range and put all their information together in a group. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean something like this: `mydata[which(mydata$marks >= 30 & mydata$marks <= 50), ]`? Your question is not very clear.

Comment: Your question in unclear, but you could possibly use `cut`.

Comment: @mrdwab: thanks! that worked :) i am still a novice in R, hence the small doubts! and supposing that I have 2 such sets of marks,mydata1 and mydata2, then how do i do the same grouping?

Comment: @Maddy: If you have two data frames `mydata1` and `mydata2`, you could use `rbind(mydata1, mydata2)` to create a combined data frame.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I am not sure what you mean with "put all their information together in a group", but here is a way to obtain a list with dataframes split up of your original data frame where each element is a data frame of the students within a mark range of 10:

```
mydata <- data.frame(
  id = 1:100,
  name = paste0("a",1:100),
  marks = sample(20:100,100,TRUE),
  gender = sample(c("female","male"),100,TRUE))

split(mydata,cut(mydata$marks,seq(20,100,by=10)))
```

Answer (score 5):

I think that @Sacha's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12315805/1270695) should suffice for what you need to do, even if you have more than one set.

You haven't explicitly said how you want to "group" the data in your original post, and in your comment, where you've added a second dataset, you haven't explicitly said whether you plan to "merge" these first (`rbind` would suffice, as recommended in the comment).

So, with that, here are several options, each with different levels of detail or utility in the output. Hopefully one of them suits your needs.

First, here's some sample data.

```
# Two data.frames (myData1, and myData2)
set.seed(1)
myData1 <- data.frame(id = 1:20, 
                      name = paste("a", 1:20, sep = ""),
                      marks = sample(20:100, 20, replace = TRUE),
                      gender = sample(c("F", "M"), 20, replace = TRUE))
myData2 <- data.frame(id = 1:17,
                      name = paste("b", 1:17, sep = ""),
                      marks = sample(30:100, 17, replace = TRUE),
                      gender = sample(c("F", "M"), 17, replace = TRUE))
```

Second, different options for "grouping".

- *Option 1*: Return (in a `list`) the values from `myData1` and `myData2` which match a given condition. *For this example, you'll end up with a list of two `data.frame`s.*

  ```
  lapply(list(myData1 = myData1, myData2 = myData2), 
         function(x) x[x$marks >= 30 & x$marks <= 50, ])
  ```
- *Option 2*: Return (in a `list`) each dataset split into two, one for `FALSE` (doesn't match the stated condition) and one for `TRUE` (does match the stated condition). In other words, creates four groups. *For this example, you'll end up with a nested list with two list items, each with two `data.frame`s.*

  ```
  lapply(list(myData1 = myData1, myData2 = myData2), 
         function(x) split(x, x$marks >= 30 & x$marks <= 50))
  ```
- *Option 3*: More flexible than the first. This is essentially @Sacha's example extended to a list. You can set your breaks wherever you would like, making this, in my mind, a really convenient option. *For this example, you'll end up with a nested list with two list items, each with multiple `data.frame`s.*

  ```
  lapply(list(myData1 = myData1, myData2 = myData2),
         function(x) split(x, cut(x$marks, 
                                  breaks = c(0, 30, 50, 75, 100), 
                                  include.lowest = TRUE)))
  ```
- *Option 4*: Combine the data first and use the grouping method described in Option 1. *For this example, you will end up with a single `data.frame` containing only values which match the given condition.*

  ```
  # Combine the data. Assumes all the rownames are the same in both sets
  myDataALL <- rbind(myData1, myData2)
  # Extract just the group of scores you're interested in
  myDataALL[myDataALL$marks >= 30 & myDataALL$marks <= 50, ]
  ```
- *Option 5*: Using the combined data, `split` the data into two groups: one group which matches the stated condition, one which doesn't. *For this example, you will end up with a list with two `data.frame`s.*

  ```
  split(myDataALL, myDataALL$marks >= 30 & myDataALL$marks <= 50)
  ```

I hope one of these options serves your needs!

Comment: @Maddy, why do you want to use explicit loops? `lapply` is one of R's internal way of replicating looping behavior, but generally in a faster way. That doesn't mean you *have* to avoid loops, but why use them when they are not necessary? By the way, which option was the most helpful for your needs?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same kind of issue and after researching some answers on stack overflow I came up with the following solution :

Step 1 : Define range
Step 2 : Find the elements that fall in the range
Step 3 : Plot

A sample code is as shown below:

```
   range = NULL
   for(i in seq(0, max(all$downlink), 2000)){
    range <- c(range, i)
   }
   counts <- numeric(length(range)-1);
   for(i in 1:length(counts)) {
   counts[i] <- length(which(all$downlink>=range[i] & all$downlink<range[i+1]));
   }
   countmax = max(counts)
   a = round(countmax/1000)*1000
   barplot(counts, col= rainbow(16), ylim = c(0,a))
```